# Ubuntu 22.04 refuses to boot

Tags: boot, apt, grub2, bash, updates

I observed my IntelliJ wasn't opening, so I opened my terminal (see below image),

[image]

and ran ‘apt-get update’. But still, InteliJ still refused to open. So, I rebooted and Ubuntu refused to boot — stopping at the below image.

[image]

Comment: Could you press ctrl + alt + F4 and login there?

Comment: Yes. I'm in. What’s next?

Comment: could you enter `startx`?

Comment: “Unable to connect to the X server. Server error. Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console.”

Comment: could you add some hardware/configuration details? Did you use Uefi,which GPU, which CPU?, you can try to `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and maybe the problem get solved

Comment: I would just go ahead to backup and reinstall Ubuntu